# How to get array's original value in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swiftui

If i have an array like this:

`@State private var names = ["Steve", "Bill", "Elon", "Jeff", "Michael"]`

and i remove its items onAppear, how can i get the original `names.count` value despite the elements being removed?

I tried creating a copy this way: `var namesCopy = names` but it's just a reference and i ended up with 2 variables referencing the same array

Comment: You have to have a second variable

Comment: You can keep track how many times an element was removed and add the current count to get the original count.

Comment: can you explain it better with an answer please? @cora

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use original as separated storage, like

```
let original = ["Steve", "Bill", "Elon", "Jeff", "Michael"]
@State private var names = [String]()
```

and filter to set `names` as we need

```
.onAppear {
  names = original.filter { ... }   // choose from original as needed
}
```

Comment: How to choose the entire array?

Comment: names = original

Comment: Is it possible to create a computed property instead of having ```onAppear { names = original }``` ?

Comment: computed property will not update view until it depends on dynamic property (like state)

Answer (score 1):

You'd have something like this:

```
@State private var names = ["Steve", "Bill", "Elon", "Jeff", "Michael"]
@State private var originalCount: Int? = nil

.onAppear {
    originalCount = names.count
    
    names.removeAll()
}
```